# Type properties of merged interface declaration

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-declaration

I'm having trouble extending the interfaces of third-party libraries globally, as importing other files in a root-level will cause the declaration file to not be global anymore.

Here's an example:

I'd like to add a property "user" of type "MyUser" on Express's Request object.
If it was of type MyUser, I could simply do the following:

```
declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    user: string;
  }
}
```

and then somewhere else:

```
...
function(..., req: Request, ...) {
  ...
  req.user; //its a string
  ...
}
```

and everything would work perfectly. However, doing the following does not work:

```
import MyUser from "../../src/types/MyUser";
declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    user: MyUser;
  }
}
```

because I now have a top-level import. Is there no way to avoid it? What's the point of being able to merge declarations, if you can't even use your own types within them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an import, your file is a module and thus any definition is local (without imports the file is a legacy script file and everything in it is global).

To put the interface in the global scope and use imports use `declare global`

```
import MyUser from "../../src/types/MyUser";
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
           user: MyUser;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives me the error "A 'declare' modifier cannot be used in an already ambient context" on the second declare.

Comment: @Fly wops forgot to delete the extra `declare`. Fixed

Comment: Ah, I see. The compiler now complains about my declaration of user, "All declarations of 'user' must have identical modifiers.". I don't see where else I would have declared user so that I could have varying modifiers, though. Any idea why this is?

Comment: That should work, unless `user` is also defined in the `express` version

Comment: Ah, it's also defined by the passport library. However, it should be defined as "any" (which is why I want to add my own type on top of it)

Comment: Ah, got it, I was missing an optional parameter (user?: MyUser). It seems to work now, thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, it actually still complains that it was defined differently in express...